# Simple linear regression seems off

Tags: regression, least-squares

I have the following datapoints:
$$p1(52,730)$$
$$p2(53,409)$$
$$p3(52,250)$$
$$p4(52,90)$$
Now I want to find the best fitting line between these points.
When I use simple linear regression I get
$$y = 52.33 x - 2364.67$$
However, I would expect a much higher slope, since the points are nearly on a vertical line. When I plot the line and the points, I also visually see that the found line is not optimal, in other words I would be able to draw a line with less distance to the points. 
E.g. if I draw a line from one end of my graph to the other I get
$$p_{y0}: (45,0)$$
$$p_{y816}: (60,816)$$
This seems way off. I would expect something where x is close to 52. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Don't forget distances are measuredvertically. Maybe you should consider regression of $x$ with regressor $y$, or regression with minimal euclidian distance (it's like a principal component analysis with 1 axis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution was to make a linear regression of $x$ on $y$ instead of $y$ on $x$ as proposed in the question.

line of regression of Y on X 
$$y-\bar{y} = \tfrac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_{x}^{2}}(x-\bar{x})$$
line of regression of X on Y 
$$x-\bar{x} = \tfrac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_{y}^{2}}(y-\bar{y})$$
By using the points shown above we get
Finding the arithmetic means:
$$\bar{x}=\tfrac{209}{4}=52.25$$
$$\bar{y}=\tfrac{1479}{4}=369.75$$
Calculating the covariance:
$$cos(X,Y)=\tfrac{77317}{4}-52.25*369.75=9,8125$$
Calculating the variances:
$$\sigma_{x}^{2}=\tfrac{10921}{4}-52.25^2=0,1875$$
$$\sigma_{y}^{2}=\tfrac{770781}{4}-369.75^2=55980,1875$$
Linear regression of y on x:
$$y-369.75 = \tfrac{9,8125}{0,1875}(x-52,25)$$
$$y=52,\bar{3}x-2364,\bar{6}$$
Linear regression of x on y:
$$x-52,25 = \tfrac{9,8125}{55980,1875}(y-369,75)$$
$$y=5704x-297716$$
The linear regression of $x$ on $y$ gave the results I was looking for (note that the results are rounded).
 More information on this issue can be found here: [What is the difference between linear regression on y with x and x with y](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22718)

Answer (score 0):

As there are four points:
$$n=4$$
Computing sums:
$$S_x=\sum x_i=209$$
$$S_y=\sum y_i=1479$$
$$S_{xx}=\sum x_i^2=10921$$
$$S_{xy}=\sum x_iy_i=77317$$
$$S_{yy}=\sum y_i^2=$$
Computing $\hat\alpha$ and $\hat\beta$
$$\hat \beta=\frac{nS_{xy}-S_xS_y}{nS_{xx}-S_x^2}=52.\bar3$$
$$\hat \alpha=\frac1nS_y-\hat\beta\frac1nS_x=-2364.\bar6$$

---

Your questions:
Yes it does have a high slope i.e. $52.\bar3$ or at an angle of $88.905^o\sim90^o$
This is the best simple regression possible until you want to minimize specific parameters such as sum of cube of distances, etc.